# Which painting tool is better? sponge paint roller roller, woven roller or spray paint?. Do you have a preference?

Tags: painting

I have a large surface to paint, a house actually. I've used all tools before and I wanted your advice on which tool do you prefer for larger surfaces. I have to prime, and put 2 finish layers.

EDIT:
So to be precise:

10 feet walls, about 8 rooms, 1800 sq ft house. Brand new gyproc just installed. So I'll first do a coat of primer of course. I was wondering if I could dare spray paint to go faster then roller, I've only sprayed outside before. It will take me forever with a roller to put 3 layers. For now it's all white with 1 accent wall per room and texture doesn't really matter that much to me, it's mostly speed and make a good enough job.

Comment: What type of surface primarily, stucco, smooth wood siding, rough-sawn plank siding, cedar shingle siding, log cabin?

Comment: It **depends** on many factors. *i.e.* choosing to spray has a considerable cost in masking things you don't want sprayed, or having overspray *everywhere.* Roller cover type depends on the surface (mostly) and the paint (somewhat.)

Comment: I agree it depends but as an opinion type question it is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

They are all "best" in certain conditions.

Spraying is "best" for large surface areas when overspray can be mitigated for example.

Rollers are good for relatively smooth surfaces and

Brushes are good for tiny difficultly shaped areas and cutting in.

Comment: Spraying is good when the paint is quite liquid, or can be thinned and remain effective.   Also when the thing you're painting has depth, like painting a wooden trellis.